# Plants vs. Zombies 2 Piñata Party mini-game location?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

An update released today includes a piñata party mini-game. Where is it in the game? I can't find it.

Comment: It says that the piñata party is a 24 hour event, so maybe one will start at midnight.

Comment: And what's that thing about "Penny's dashboard"? Never seen that anywhere, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piñata Parties are every Monday and Thursday at 4:00 PM PST:
[image: PvZ 2 Piñata Party times]

Answer (score 2):

It said that the pinata party appears on Monday and Thursday on the app store on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it acts the same as the Yeti game (which appears once a day).